# Dual of a function $f$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

We have that dual of $f$ is given by $f^*(x) = \sup_w [w^T \alpha - f(w)]$.

We want to find the dual of $f$, which is given by

$
f(z)=
\begin{cases}
 1 - z^Tx - \frac{\gamma}{2} &\text{if}\, 1-z^Tx > \gamma\\
 \frac{1}{2\gamma}(1 - z^Tx) &\text{if}\, 1-z^Tx \in [0, \gamma]\\
      0&\text{if } 1-z^Tx < 0
\end{cases}
$

I tried to consider $\nabla f(z) = \begin{cases}
 -x &\text{if}\, 1-z^Tx > \gamma\\
 (x)\frac{1}{\gamma}(z^Tx-1) &\text{if}\, 1-z^Tx \in [0, \gamma]\\
      0&\text{if } 1-z^Tx < 0
\end{cases}$

but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Proceed to do what?

Comment: Make queries with the keywords "Legendre-Fenchel duality"

Comment: why would you want this for a function that is not convex?